# Is it possible to load a custom directive after angularJS is compiled?

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive to calculate the height of a divs.

```
// Directive to log a height. We have to add on some value to a final height, because css style will be undefined.
rootApp.directive('logHeightCategories', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.prepMaxHeightCat = element.prop('offsetHeight');
            scope.value = 0;
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.maxHeightCat = scope.value + scope.prepMaxHeightCat;
            }, 0);
        }
    };
}]);
```

The css rule `max-height: {{maxHeightCat}}px` is applied to that div for animation purpose.
Nevertheless, a flicker effect destroy that desire goal. So I've added `ng-cloak` to `display:none` for that div.

I think `ng-cloak` is rendered as last, therefore I think my directive `logHeightCategories` is executed before. So I always get `0px` result.

*...even I've added a `$timeout` function in hope I would overcome execution time, but I think it's not the case.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```js
rootApp.directive('logHeightCategories', ['$timeout', '$compile',
  function($timeout,$compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.prepMaxHeightCat = element.prop('offsetHeight');
        scope.value = 0;
        scope.maxHeightCat = scope.value + scope.prepMaxHeightCat;      
        scope.$watch(attrs.logHeightCategories, function(html) {
          element.html(html);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: I've applied the div with scope `prepMaxHeightCat`, because I see you excluded math, but anyway I got `0px` output.

Comment: i missed that line. added. no need to `$.timeout` you can put `scope.$watch` on `attrs` and when it changes completed do `compile`  `scope` that is what the idea is.

Comment: There is also referenceError from console log that `ele is not defined`. I've checked the `ng-cloak` directive in angularjs file and it comes with `priority: -10`. I don't know now, whether precedence here play any role.

Comment: i have updated answer, that is your `element`. @DominikK

Comment: For the change, `$compile is not defined`. But all that doesn't seems to solve my problem. Probably it answers the question and it works well, but there may be something else behind that, why I got output `0px` with `ng-cloak` defined on the div.

Comment: added it as parameter. `ng-cloak` not compiled and act as `class` and you make it `display:none`. One scope directives are compiled it removes `ng-cloak` from every where it founds. @DominikK

Comment: `$compile` is not a function, that what's log says.

Comment: You have not added `'$compile'` after `'$timeout'` in injection.

Comment: The error message has disappeared, but it didn't solved the problem I'm having.